# Creating Tables on Network Activation

Tags: plugins, database

I'm working on a plugin which creates a new table.  I've got it working fine on a single site install, but I'm not so sure about multisite.

How do I create a table for each blog on network activation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually advise against doing that.

If you create a table for each blog on network activation you'll start running into scalability issues.  Some Multisite networks are small (2-10 sites) and wouldn't cause too many issues.  But larger networks (1000+ sites) would add a *lot* to the database if they added their plugin.

Instead, I'd recommend creating a *single* table and adding a "blog_ID" column to the table.  If you're running a single site installation, just set that column to be 0 and run everything normally.  But on a Multisite installation, set that column to whatever blog is using that data.

A single table is easier to manage.

Besides, if you create a new table for each blog, not only do you need the massive creation script when first activating the plugin, but you need to hook into the site creation mechanism to create a new table whenever a site is created.

Comment: I got to thinking about that after I posted the question.  If it gets activated net work wide, what would `$wpdb->prefix` return on each individual blog? Would I be able to use that still?

Comment: Yes. The database prefix is set in the `wp-config.php` file and is used only to differentiate tables if you install two instances of WordPress to the same database (two *separate* instances, not a multisite setup).

Comment: On blog 1 (the root site), `$wpdb->prefix` returns the naked prefix defined i wp-config.  On other sites, you get things like `wp_2_` as the prefix.  Any way around that?

Comment: My mistake. In a multisite installation you need to use `$wpdb->base_prefix` instead.

Comment: Also, you can use `$wpdb->base_prefix` in a single-site setup to return the same as `$wpdb->prefix`

Comment: I just found that out, actually.  Did some poking around in the wpdb class and found the `set_prefix` method sets `base_prefix` regardless.  Edited the codex to include `base_prefix`, seemed like a thing that should be in there.